# cut / grep and df -h

Tags: scripting, grep, cut

How can I grep or cut the "173G" under "Verf"?

I need this for Unix scripting in school.

```
jonas@jonaspc:~/$ df -h /dev/sda2
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda2       293G    121G  173G   42% /media/Windows
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most comfortable solution for such task is `awk`:

```sh
df -h /dev/sda2 | awk 'NR==2{print$4}'
```

Or if more partitions are listed, you can pick the right line by the mount point:

```sh
df -h | awk '$1=="/dev/sda2"{print$4}'
```

Is also simple with `sed`, but less nice if you need to debug it a few mounts later :

```sh
df -h /dev/sda2 | sed -rn '2s/^((\S+)\s+){4}.*/\2/p'

df -h | sed -rn '/^\/dev\/sda2/s/^((\S+)\s+){4}.*/\2/p'
```

That supposes GNU `sed`. POSIX compatible syntax includes many escaping:

```sh
df -h /dev/sda2 | sed -n '2s/^\(\(\S\+\)\s\+\)\{4\}.*/\2/p'

df -h | sed -n '/^\/dev\/sda2/s/^\(\(\S\+\)\s\+\)\{4\}.*/\2/p'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you must use grep and cut, you can do the following:

```
df -h /dev/sda2 | grep sda | cut -d" " -f14
```

But this is pretty ugly, since you have to count the spaces (-f14) and the reason @manatwork used awk. You could use `tr` or other tools to make it nicer and be able to specify the real field you want for cut:

```
df -h /dev/sda2 | grep sda | tr -s " " " " | cut -d" " -f4
```

Alternatively, newer grep supports outputing only a partial match and you can use that in combination with a bash trick:

```
df -h /dev/sda2 | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*G' | cut -d$'\n' -f3
```

The regex could be safer, but this will find all the size fields and output them one per line, while cut selects the second.

Comment: A minor point: you only need `tr -s " "`, unless you want to change the remaining space to something else.... (+1), but `-f2` should be `-f3`

Comment: I looked up the wrong field in my tests, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

All other answers here are great, but if you use **Bash**, there is no need to use external programs such as awk, sed, grep, cut etc.

The following line will do what you want:

```
{ read; read -r _ _ _ av _; } < <(df -h /dev/sda1)
```

**"$av"** will be the available size on /dev/sda1

If you want to use only the numeric part of **"$av"** ( e.g **123** in 123G ), you can use [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to trim the irrelevant part like that:

```
ir="${av##*[0-9]}"; echo "${av%$ir}"
```

or just `"${av%?}"` if you are sure that the suffix of **"$av"** is only one letter.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be `grep`/`cut`, you may be able to get the same information using `stat`. In filesystem mode, `%a` is number of free blocks and `%s` blocksize, so `%a * %s` is the free space in bytes, and you can do math to your liking with it to break it down to a more suitable unit of your choice, for example:

```
echo $((`stat -f -c "%a*%s" /media/windows/`/1024/1024/1024))GiB
```